# Cython with gettext

Tags: python, gettext, cython

I'm getting started with Cython, and running into a problem with using gettext translations in my source files.  As an example, I have a source file called **ScriptParser.py** which I'm testing compiling to a .pyd object.  This is without modification to the source at all, just trying to get the file to compile at the moment.  This file is imported from one of the main files in the project.  That main file also imports a different source file, which uses gettext to install the translation function **_()**.  The error Cython is giving me is this:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            fn += u':%i' % step

            fn += u']'
            return eval(fn)
        except:
            error(_(u'IndexError'))
                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

ScriptParser.py:416:19: undeclared name not builtin: _
```

Obviously Cython is complaining because no where in this source file is **_()** referenced or defined or anything or the sort.  So I'm wondering how I should be going about resolving this.  Do I need to change my build script to encompass more files?  Right now I'm just attempting compiling one file at a time to test for oddities and such.  I had already compiled 2 source files this way when I ran into the problem with this one.

Here's my build script for reference:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = 'testing',
    ext_modules = cythonize(['ScriptParser.py',
                              ],
                            annotate=True),
    )
```

And called with:

> setup.py build_ext --inplace

Now like I said I could just be screwing up the build process, this is my first foray into Cython.  So maybe I'm mistakenly trying to compile one source file at a time, instead of doing some "project as a whole" method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. It is just that gettext modifies `__builtin__` namespace which cython cannot know. As a workaround you could just add for all files where this occurs:

```
import __builtin__; _ = __builtin__._
```

I don't see how else you would tell cython to accept the existance of a non-standard variable in the `__builtin__` scope, but maybe you can ask the cython mailing list if there is another way to trick cython. (Note that this will also fail if the gettext stuff is not done before the import of the module. Though adding a `try: ... except: ...` clause to set `__builtin__._` to None if it does not exist yet would fix that.

EDIT: of course `_` here is at the module scope then, but I don't think this should be a problem.